Mudblazor fails to navigate to new Razor page
I have a functioning Mudblazor server side app. I added a new Razor page but when I try to navigate to that page for testing, I receive the "...nothing here..." message. I conclude that means the page was not found.
Here is the page (reduced to bare minimum for testing):
@page "/parms3"
<h3>Parms3</h3>
@code {

}

I tried navigating to this new page by adding its routing parameter to the main url like this:
https://localhost:44388/parms3
but receive the response: "Sorry, there's nothing at this address."
I expected that if the page were found, it would display the text in the  tag.
I also tried adding a link to the navigation page with the same result:
<MudNavLink Href="/parms3" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Update">Parms</MudNavLink>

Other pages in my app work just fine. I can navigate to them by the Nav menu or by manually adding their routing to the main url. Just won't navigate to my new page.

Other pages in my app work just fine. So clearly, where/how you've added the new page is the issue. But with just the information on your question unlikely anyone would be able to help you, I suggest you improve your question to be answerable.

Thanks @RBee for the suggestion. This is a server-side MudBlazor app. There are 22 other Razor pages in the app; all  are located in the "Pages" subfolder. Some of them are quite complex, but they work reliably. This new page was created in VS2022 just like the others, and also placed in the "Pages" subfolder.

MudBlazor isn't responsible for navigation. Especially since directly navigating to the page doesn't work, it's not a a MudNavLink problem. As previously stated though, there's not much information available to provide you with an answer. If you add another new page, does it work?

No - adding another new page using the "Add New Item" menu does not work. However, in probing the problem, I found a solution that completely baffles me. I selected an existing page, and right-click copied it. I then right-click pasted it back into the Pages subfolder with all my other pages. I modified the routing link to "parms3" and it WORKED! I could navigate to it manually and via the MudNavLink. Can anyone explain this one for me? (BTW, the code inside the page that works is identical to the code inside the page that didn't work - only difference is how the page was created)
